# Refactoring Filter and Map into sections for search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, filter, ecmascript-6

I have a search bar component. I would like to know how I can refactor the below code such that I can include html markup to display if there is no match. Right now the markup displays if there is a match or nothing displays if its blank.

I was getting errors when separating out the filter and map function.

```
return (
<div>
<input placeholder="Search Book Title" onChange={handleChange} />
        {
        bookList.filter(book => {
            let isMatched = (book.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()));
    
            if (query === '') {
                return ;
            } else if (isMatched) {
                return book;
            }
        }).map((book, index) => (
            <div>           
            This is the book   
            </div>
        ))
        }
    </div>
)
};
```

I was getting errors when separating out the filter and map function.

Comment: The value you return from filter function should be true or false, true if the element is to be included false otherwise.  Nothing else matters to filter.  If you try to return a non-empty string it will be the same as returning true, but the value of the string is discarded.

Comment: But how do I add html markup if there isn't a match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the filter first and assign the result to a variable.  Check if the .length is zero, if it is return your no books found markup.  Otherwise return your books that were found list.  For example

```
function getFilteredBooks() {
  let filteredBooks = bookList.filter(book => 
    book.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
  );

  if (filteredBooks.length === 0) {
    return (<div>No books</div>);
  } else {
    return books.map(book => <div>{{book.title}}</div>);
  }
}

// ... other code

return (<div> <input placeholder="Search Book Title" onChange={handleChange} />{{getFilteredBooks()}}</div>)
```

Comment: This looks good. But it doesn't work inside the return statement when I enclose it in curly braces

Comment: Ah true, I have used return in the if.  Probably needs to be wrapped in a function that you call during the other `return` .

Comment: Is that what you demonstrated? Just curious what that would look like. Feel confused with what you mean by wrapped in a function

Comment: Edited my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Ah I see it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend assigning the result of the filtered books to a variable and then use it in your rendered result -

```js
const filteredBooks = bookList.filter(book => {
  return query != ""
    && book.title.toLowerCase.includes(query.toLowerCase())
})
      
return (
  <div>
    <input placeholder="Search Book Title" onChange={handleChange} />
    { filteredBooks.length == 0
    ? <p>No matching books</p>
    : filteredBook.map((book, index) => (
        <div key={index}>           
          This is the book   
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)
```

If the filter is an expensive computation, you should `useMemo` -

```
const filteredBooks = useMemo(() => (
  bookList.filter(book => (
    query != ""
      && book.title.toLowerCase.includes(query.toLowerCase())
      && someExpensiveCondition(query) // <-
  ))
), [bookList, query])
```